# Has the Stanford Bunny ever been re-imaged?

Tags: 3d

The [photographic version](https://faculty.cc.gatech.edu/%7Eturk/bunny/stanford-bunny-photo.jpg) shows much more detailed fur than the popular [test image](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Stanford_Bunny.stl).

Comment: Hi, El-ahrairah. Welcome to the site! Do you have links for the images you're comparing?

Comment: @luser droog Probably the third picture down in this article:  https://faculty.cc.gatech.edu/~turk/bunny/bunny.html .  There are also 289 light field images (not enough angles for photogrammetry, sadly) made with a Lego Mindstorms gantry here:  http://graphics.stanford.edu/data/LF/lfs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest scan of the Stanford Bunny that I'm aware of was in January 2000, a CT scan:  “The scale of the voxel data is 0.337891 mm x 0.337891 mm x 0.5mm in the x-, y-, and z-dimensions respectively.  The greyscale units are Hounsfield units, denoting electron-density of the subject.  The data is raw 512x512 slices, unsigned, 12 bit data stored as 16bit (2-byte) pixels.”

http://graphics.stanford.edu/data/voldata/voldata.html#bunny

That link includes a download of the data, although I don't know how to open the files.  Even though the scan is later than the original 1994 range data, I'm not sure it can be considered higher resolution for 3D purposes.